# Lowest latency VNC connection with available tools

Tags: linux, ssh, emacs, putty, vnc

Good day,

I have to SSH into systems at my work and cannot seem to find the best setup to get my productivity to the level I want.

Currently I have the options to use Putty, VNC Viewer, or Bash for Windows to SSH. Each one seems to have some drawbacks though and I'm trying to find a combination that works best for me.

VNC Viewer is what I have mainly used, but I am highly sensitive to the latency that occurs due to the distance from the servers (coast to coast of the US)

To counter the latency, I tried using Bash for Windows and PUTTY. Both of these tools greatly decrease the latency, which I am happy about. The drawback then though is that although I don't mind using just a command line for the most part, I do like my instances of emacs to spawn in a new window as I find this to make me more productive when I have to be working in multiple areas.

I tried XWin and enabling X11 forwarding, which does allow the instances of emacs to spawn in their own window, but this seems to have even more lag than the GUI rendering. It's to the point where I cannot even use it. Also, there are some programs that XWin doesn't seem to allow a new window to spawn (in my case, Verdi).

Also, I like having numerous terminal tabs open at the same time to jump between. The closest solution I've found to this problem is using Putty Connection Manager, which allows me to call multiple tabs of PUTTY. With this though, my complaint is that it still doesn't function similar to an actual GUI console since each tab needs to open it's own SSH instance. Also, whenever I close the program, all of my SSH instances are closed, and are not recoverable like they are in VNC Viewer even if I disconnect or lose internet access.

Are there any setups that people use that seem to have the best results for the above mentioned issues? Any settings I should look at or free programs I should try that may result in better results? Any better GUI VNCs in terms of latency? Because, currently all I see as valid solutions are getting used to the latency or getting used to not using emacs in it's own window, but still using VNC viewer whenever I need to launch GUI programs.

All recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running tigervnc or other vnc clones that use compression to work faster?

Comment: I don't think I am able to use any other VNCs. I've tried Tiger and Tight in the past and both complain that the remote server's supported encryption types do not match any of the options available.

Comment: What about using `tramp-mode` and edit the remote files in a local emacs?

Comment: Welcome to superuser: Please read How we recommend software :- [softwarerecs.se], this question maybe viewed as opinion based Please read [ask]. Do you have a pro's and con's list so it is easier to view give us a lead on what is more important you as a user , again welcome to superuser

Comment: I use x2go now. Seems to be a lot faster and smoother than VNC or X11.